# WHat is wrong with my code, try to save the changed txt file, but nothing happens

Tags: java, save, load, export

Hey friends try to replace some commas in my database, can someoone give me advide what wrong is with my code, have already the replace eveything is done, but nothing happends

```
try {

  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Sei_Erfolgreich/Desktop/convert.txt"));
   String zeile; try {
    while ((zeile = br.readLine()) != null) {
        zeile = zeile.replaceAll("\",\"", "\uffff")
              .replaceAll(",", "")
              .replaceAll("\uffff", "\",\"");
        System.out.println(zeile);
                    }
        File newTextFile = new File("C:/Users/Sei_Erfolgreich/Desktop/convert2.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
     fw.write(zeile);
     fw.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I've removed the couchdb tag as this question isn't really about couchdb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are writing string after coming  out from loop so that string whould be null, try out this code

```
    try {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("C:/Users/Sei_Erfolgreich/Desktop/convert.txt"));
        String zeile;

        try {
            File newTextFile = new File("C:/Users/Sei_Erfolgreich/Desktop/convert2.txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
            while ((zeile = br.readLine()) != null) {
                zeile = zeile.replaceAll("\",\"", "\uffff").replaceAll(",",
                        "").replaceAll("\uffff", "\",\"");
                System.out.println(zeile);
                fw.write(zeile);
            }


            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Sei_Erfolgreich/Desktop/convert.txt"));
File newTextFile = new File("C:/Users/Sei_Erfolgreich/Desktop/convert2.txt");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
String zeile; 
try {
    while ((zeile = br.readLine()) != null) {
        zeile = zeile.replaceAll("\",\"", "\uffff").replaceAll(",", "").replaceAll("\uffff", "\",\"");
        System.out.println(zeile);
        fw.write(zeile);
    }
fw.close();
}
```

Earlier what you were doing, you read the file until last line and saving only one last line instead of whole file text.

Comment: But now there is another problem with the comma, the comma between rows are also gone, so i need to keep up this },{ also alive

Answer (score 0):

You're writing `null` because you don't write until after your `while` loop (which terminates when `zeile` is `null`). Also, you should be closing everything in a finally block (or using a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Also, I suggest you use a `PrintWriter` so you can match your `System.out.println()`(s). Something like,

```
File newTextFile = new File("C:/Users/Sei_Erfolgreich/Desktop/convert2.txt");

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
        "C:/Users/Sei_Erfolgreich/Desktop/convert.txt"));
        PrintWriter fw = new PrintWriter(newTextFile)) {
    String zeile;
    while ((zeile = br.readLine()) != null) {
        zeile = zeile.replaceAll("\",\"", "\uffff").replaceAll(",", "")
                .replaceAll("\uffff", "\",\"");
        System.out.println(zeile);
        fw.println(zeile);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```